# Selecting random records retrieved in API - Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I have very little knowledge on APIs and this is my first time creating a game. I am creating a game and I need to select random users to win the game. Currently, I have an API that allows me to retrieve the details of the current logged in user that I can retrieve. However, I do not know how to randomly select users to win the game.

I have tried this code below but I am getting the error saying

> 'ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is my code:

Provider

```
getStaff(){
return this.http.get<StaffRecords>(`${this.staffApiUrl}//some api
  {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'))});
```

}

.ts file of the page

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private christmasProvider: ChristmasProvider) {

this.christmasProvider.getStaff().pipe(
  map((staffResult: StaffRecords) => staffResult && staffResult.records)
).subscribe(staffed => {
  if (staffed){
    this.staff = staffed;
    let randomStaff = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.staff.length);
    this.staff = [this.staff[randomStaff]];
    console.log(this.staff);
  }
});}
```

If I do not use the Math.random() function, I will be able to retrieve the records like this:
[image]

I am also unable to randomly select users to win. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: it looks like `staffed` is not an array - move your `console.log` up to check

Comment: I included the results I got after moving console.log up. Please check.

Comment: try reducing to simply `this.staff = staffed[Math.floor(Math.random() * staffed.length)];`

Comment: I get `[ts] Type 'Staff' is not assignable to type 'Staff[]'.
[ts]Type 'Staff' is not assignable to type 'Staff[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Staff'.` when I do that

Comment: it wants an array: `this.staff = [staffed[Math.floor(Math.random() * staffed.length)]];`

Comment: ohhh i see. thanks :)